# Can I submit a form via mailto: if I can't process it on the server?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm creating a small website for a client with a PHP form processor.  What I would like is for the contact form to fallback to the `mailto` method if PHP is not available in the Web Server.  It seems odd, but I just need to make sure they can deploy this anywhere.

Right now I have:

```
form method="post" action="my_form_processor.php"
```

Is there anyway to handle this?

Comment: Submitting forms via mailto: is ... *messy* ... at best.  It will also fail unless the user has a local mail client installed.  This plan might not work out very well.

Comment: Portability is nice, but requesting that PHP is available is not an unreasonable request. Next thing they'll want it to run without a server!

Comment: Well, you could use one of the following technologies as fallback: ASP.NET, node.js, JSP, Ruby On Rails, ... It all depends on what technology you want to support.

Comment: @ZombieHunter Assuming PHP "is not available", I do not think those selections would often be "fallbacks" .. (one thing PHP has going strong for it is ubiquity with cheap/basic hosting)

Answer (score 1):

You could offer two files: index.html and index.php in a directory. The content is the same, except for the way the form works.

If php is installed, it will (usually, can change based on server config) prefer index.php over index.html when serving the homepage. If php isn't there, the server will instead serve index.html.

When linking, just go to the directory rather than the file. e.g. link to example.com/foo/ instead of example.com/foo/index.php.

Though I agree with the comments saying you might want to do something else, like require php since form mailto kinda sucks and php is really common.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a bad idea, but not that hard to solve technically:

- Set a javascript variable using php: `var myVar = "<?php echo 'php'; ?>";`
- Test in javascript if `myVar === 'php'` and change the `action` attribute of the form if it turns out `false`.

Of course this would also fail if the visitor has javascript disabled so you are better off giving your client a list of server requirements.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the possibility that JS might be turned off, which we often ignore.

Comment: Another problem with these clever php solutions though is you'll have to make sure the server is configured to  a) send the file through the php interpreter if present, b) serve it with the appropriate html mime type if not, and c) probably take care of the directory index too.

If you're going to reconfigure the server to do that stuff, you might as well just have the server send different html if php isn't installed and cut the javascript out of the picture.

Comment: @Adam D. Ruppe To be honest, this is just one technical solution to a problem that you should never have. Like I stated at the end, just give you client a list of server requirements. You are always going to need some kind of technology, so just specify it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bad idea. If your client refuses to install a serverside language, they won't get a dynamic website.

Just for fun, you could probably do something like this:

```
<script>
    if ('<?php ?>'.length != 0) {
        $('#form').attr('action', 'mailto:fallback@example.com');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, I ended up going with ajax/php.  Anyhow your answer is right on the money of what I was looking for.